# Table not in order with code?

Tags: tables

I have a table that shows up after the example and exercises subsection. Is there a way to not anchor it to anything and have it appear in its original position in the code?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[margin=1.1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{multirow}
\newtheorem{example}{Example}[section]
\newtheorem{exercise}{Exercise}[section]
\begin{document}
\begin{table}[ht]
\centering
\caption{Set Identities}
\begin{tabular}{ll}
$\overline{(\overline{A})} = A$   & Double Negative \\
$A \cap U = A$  & \multirow{2}{*}{Identity Laws} \\
$A \cup \emptyset = A$  & \\
$A \cup U = U$  & \multirow{2}{*}{Domination Laws} \\
$A \cap \emptyset = \emptyset$  & \\
$A \cup A = A$  & \multirow{2}{*}{Idempotent Laws} \\
$A \cap A = A$  &  \\
$A \cup B = B \cup A$  & \multirow{2}{*}{Commutative Laws} \\
$A \cap B = B \cap A$  & \\
$A \cup (B \cup C) = (A \cup B) \cup C$  & \multirow{2}{*}{Associative Laws} \\
$A \cap (B \cap C) = (A \cap B) \cap C$  & \\
$A \cup (B \cap C) = (A \cup B) \cap (A \cup C)$ & \multirow{2}{*}   {Distributive Laws} \\
$A \cap (B \cup C) = (A \cap B) \cup (A \cap C)$  & \\
$\overline{A \cap B} = \overline{A} \cup \overline{B}$  & \multirow{2}{*}  {De Morgan's Laws} \\
$\overline{A \cup B} = \overline{A} \cap \overline{B}$  & \\
$A \cup (A \cap B) = A$  & \multirow{2}{*}{Absorption Laws} \\
$A \cap (A \cup B) = A$  & \\
$\overline{A} \cup A = U$ & \multirow{2}{*}{Negation Laws} \\
$\overline{A} \cap A = \emptyset$ &
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\begin{example}
Find the intersection of $A = \{2k|k \in \mathbb{N}\} \text{ and } B = \{3k|k \in \mathbb{N}\}$.

\smallskip \noindent
\textbf{Solution:} The set $A$ represents all natural numbers divisible by $2$ and the set $B$ is the set of all natural numbers divisible by $3$. $A \cap B$ is the set of all natural numbers divisible by $2$ and $3$, therefore $A \cap B = \{6k | k \in N\}$.
\end{example}

\subsection*{Exercises}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Sounds like you actually do want to anchor it instead of it floating.  Look at the floats package.  Lots of similar already answered questions on this platform.